# Is there a Ruby database migration gem, that helps you move content from an old structure to a new structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, data-migration

Are there any Ruby gems/libraries that help you migrate from an old DB structure to a new structure? ActiveRecord migrations do a good job keeping track of a new db structure, but I wonder if there's something that helps you migrate an entire legacy db to a new structure:

```
transfer_from(:source_table => 'person', :destination_table => 'dudes_and_dudets') do

  from :name, :to => :full_name

  from :dob, :to => :age do |dob|    # this would, for example, load the result  
    (Date.today - dob)/60/60/24/365  # of the block into :age
  end

end
```

(I realize you could do these transforms just as easily with AR, but I'm *hoping* the magic library would have many more transforms.

Berns

Comment: Your code snippet is an interesting interface and peace of code for a yet-to-create gem. +1

Comment: I agree. Quick; someone get @wycats to look at it!

Comment: That's some might sensible syntax there. I might take a crack at implementation if no one else has by the time I've got some spare time to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've begun working on this.

If anyone would like to give tips on a better/more idiomatic, or more efficient implementation, please let me know.

http://github.com/btelles/legacy_migrations

**edit**:

I now have this exact syntax working on the above github repository... plan to add a few rake tasks for mapping the old structure to new ActiveRecord classes, and more transforms...in case anyone's interested.

It's also on gemcutter/rubygems: gem install legacy_migrations

Answer (score 2):

You can access all your models from within a migration, and thus handle all your data migrations right there too. If you already knew this, and your question was about a neater way of doing it, then of course this is not the answer you're looking for.

One problem with your example is that you can't migrate down to an earlier version, but only because of the block feature you demonstrate in conversions.

I admit that your example is nice and terse, but here's a regular migration example any way:

```
class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # This is only needed if the new table will have the same name.
    # Move the old one aside.
    rename_table :users, :old_users

    # The new table structure
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.date   :age
    end

    # Data migration
    OldUsers.all.each do |orig|
      User.create!(
        :full_name => orig.name,
        :age => (Date.today - orig.dob)/60/60/24/365
      )
    end

    # Clean up
    drop_table :old_users
  end

  def self.down
    # Exercise for the reader!
  end
end

# Temporary class for accessing the old table during conversion
class OldUsers < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

Comment: Yeah, not what I was looking for. Thanks though. Basically, (and this is the second time this has happened, and I assume there'll be a third), we are recreating an old system in Rails, and the old data has a really unorthodox structure (for the contemporary programmer, at least). For example, a we have foreign key that is made up of the parent table's primary key and the first 3 characters of some other column...oh joy, right? And yes, it'd be easy to do this in migrations, but a library that has convenient little helpers or reports the number of mismatches would be very helpful at this point.

Comment: Using Ruby to migrate data can be very slow.  Imagine there're 10,000 records in the "old_users" table and looping through that.  Using straight SQL is much faster.  In addition, you must rename your model from User to OldUser for this migration to run successfuly?  If you use straight SQL it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something like (what I think) you're describing, and I used [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) for it.  Sequel is adaptable and generally useful and can work with SQL directly in a fairly handy fashion and can access multiple different sorts of DBs.

The documentation is very handy, and I recommend it entirely.

[Here's an example](http://www.hokstad.com/using-sequel-and-ruby-to-import-the-geonames-database.html) of using sequel to take a huge arbitrarily flatfile from [geonames](http://geonames.org) and use it to fill out a db and make queries.   This is probably a good example for you to make something to do what you want.

It's rails-agnostic.  doesn't need to be attached to a model, migration, or anything else other than a couple gems.

Comment: Oops...I think you forgot to put in the example...the link takes me to the geonames website.

Comment: btelles -- added it, but also just http://www.hokstad.com/using-sequel-and-ruby-to-import-the-geonames-database.html

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few for moving databases without transforms. I remember the Rails Envy guys talking about a gem (but it's a while back and I haven't got time to go digging). Have a look on railsenvy.com?

Comment: They were probably talking about the active-warehouse/etl tool by Anthony Eden, which I tried and ended up finding it didn't suit my needs for a one-time data transfer. If you find the time to go digging, please do come back. I'm very interested in not having to build this library myself :-)

Comment: Hmmm ... you *could* export the whole thing using to_xml and then hack some xsl - but that's too nasty for words.

When I do this stuff I tend to write a script in SQL, usually creating temporary tables on the way to do the transforms. Also been known to dump the SQL out and use tools like sed, but that's not trivial.

If you can come up with some queries that produce your target from the source you'll be laughing. If you need some help my SQL-fu ain't so bad, main thing is to create temporary tables on the way to break things out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Trucker Gem](https://github.com/mokolabs/trucker) it works great for migrating legacy data into a Rails application. It creates active record objects for each table in the legacy database and puts them in app/models/legacy. Inside these classes you can then define how they map onto your new classes.

Comment: Hi Chris, I saw (your?) presentation on SD Ruby. Want to talk about merging Legacy Migrations and Trucker? Yours seems to automate the setup process very well, whereas mine seems to help with the conversion of data in a few interesting ways. Just let me know if you're interested.

Answer (score -1):

1. config your database in config/database.yml
2. `rake db:schema:dump`
3. convert schema.rb into db/migrate/001_create_database.rb
4. you can generate other migration to maintain your database schema

Comment: I think this is not what the author asked for. The question is about content migration, not structure migration.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with hurikhan...thanks, though. (edited question to clarify)