# Rails: rename globalize column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rename, globalize

The rails globalize gem  docs are great, but I can't find a solution, what I have to do, when I want to rename a column.

Last Year I did that, to add the translation fields.

```rb
  def up
    remove_column :news, :name
    News.add_translation_fields! name: :string
  end

  def down
    add_column :news, :name, :string, default: nil
    remove_column :news_translations, :name
  end
```

Now I want to rename the column "name" to "title", without loosing my data and translations. How do I have to write the migration file?

Comment: Am I missing something here?... Can you not just do `def change; rename_column :news, :name, :title; end`?

Comment: That. If it's actually more complex then there are a number of solutions that boil down to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135600/438992 somewhere under the covers.

Comment: mhh, But I don't want to rename the News model, just the column.

Comment: `rename_column :news, :name` means "in the news table, rename the name column" - it won't rename the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the column **on the news translations table** directly:

```
def change
  rename_column :news_translations, :name, :title
end
```