# How do I insert data only if it matches a certain condition from one table to another table in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, data-migration, rails-migrations

I'm somewhat of a begginer to SQL and migrations in general, so it's possible my approach is completely wrong here, but bear with me ;)

I have a Company model that has attributes for SMTP mailing configuration (like `smtp_address` and `smtp_port`), which are optional.

However, I now need my User model to be able to have an SMTP configuration as well, so I created a SMTPConfiguration model with attributes `address`, `port`, and a polymorphic association to `smtpable`. This model will belong either to the User or Company model

What I'd like to do now is migrate the data I already have in the companies table over to the SMTP configurations table, which sounds pretty straightforward, except I want to create a new SMTPConfiguration ONLY if the Company actually has the `smtp_address` and `smtp_port` set. If `smtp_address` and `smtp_port` are not present, the Company should not have a belonging SMTPConfiguration.

This would be fairly easy to do using Ruby conditions and ActiveRecord, but from what I've read inserting rows individually with ActiveRecord can be reaaally long for large databases, so it is a much better idea to use raw SQL. Turns out I suck at SQL :( .

I've searched on StackOverFlow quite a bit, and using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6136106/8905332) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612267/move-sql-data-from-one-table-to-another), I came up with something like

```
execute <<-SQL
  INSERT INTO smtp_configurations (address, port, smtpable_id)
  SELECT (c.smtp_address, c.smtp_port, c.id)
  FROM companies c
  WHERE c.smtp_address <> NULL
SQL
```

This wouldn't work since it doesn't set `created_at`, `updated_at` and `smtpable_type`, but to be honest I'm out of ideas. Could the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem be of any use?

I am using Rails 5.1.4 and Postgres 10.3

Comment: What is `smtpable_type` ? I can provide example, but need to understand how to obtain that column in your app

Comment: Am I right `smtpable_type` is always 'Company' ?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk  `smtpable_type` is the type of the polymorphic association. It is not always Company, it can also be User

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk The column is there because my SMTPConfiguration table has the following reference: `t.references :smtpable, polymorphic: true, index: true`

Comment: You do `SELECT ... FROM companies c`. How `smtpable_type` could be 'User' ? :)

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood what you meant. You're right, smtpable_type is always 'Company'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code in your **migration**:

```
created_at = Time.current.to_s(:db)
insert_clause = <<-SQL
  INSERT INTO smtp_configurations(
    smtpable_id,
    smtpable_type,
    address,
    port,
    created_at,
    updated_at
  )
  SELECT
    c.id,
    'Company',
    c.smtp_address,
    c.smtp_port,
    '#{created_at}',
    '#{created_at}'
  FROM companies c
  WHERE (c.smtp_address IS NOT NULL) AND (c.port IS NOT NULL)
SQL

execute(insert_clause)
```

**UPDATED**: Changed code for plain Rails.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast Pavel :)
I am getting the following error:
`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"` at the `:smtpable_type` line

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot for the quick answer :)