# Rails migration : how to move attribute from model to other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Report model that have a step_id attribute , and I want to move this attribute to ReportSheets model, is there a way to generate the migration from terminal or should I write the code by my self :

```
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    create_table :reports, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.uuid     :declarant_id

      t.integer  :reference
      t.datetime :sent_at
      t.uuid     :step_id

      t.boolean  :is_archived, default: false
      t.uuid     :updated_by_id
      t.string   :device_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :reports, :reference, unique: true

    add_index :reports, :declarant_id
    add_index :reports, :device_id
    add_index :reports, :step_id

  end
end


class CreateReportSheets < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    create_table :report_sheets, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string  :title,        null: false
      t.boolean :is_template,  default: false
      t.uuid    :report_id
      t.integer :seed_number
      t.integer :order
      t.hstore  :steps, array: true, default: '{}', null: false

      t.uuid  :template_id

      t.boolean :is_archived,   default: false
      t.uuid    :updated_by_id
      t.string  :device_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :report_sheets, :report_id
    add_index :report_sheets, :template_id
    add_index :report_sheets, :seed_number
    add_index :report_sheets, :is_template

    add_index :report_sheets, :is_archived
    add_index :report_sheets, :device_id
  end
end
```

and in case of there is a relation between the 2 models like  add_index :reports, :step_id ?

Comment: Do you need to change only database schema? May be you need to migrate `step` column data from one table to another also?

Comment: yes I need to migrate step column data also to ReportSheet table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move a column (with contents) to another table in a Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135600/how-do-i-move-a-column-with-contents-to-another-table-in-a-rails-migration)