# Copy an ActionText field to a plain text field Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, actiontext

I need to search text in a Rails ActionText field. Couldn't find any solutions, so I created a text plain field and when the ActionText form is submitted, a `before_ save self.content_plain_text = content.body.to_plain_text` is run. This works fine and I can search in `content_plain_text`.

But now I need to update the `content_plain_text` for all the already existing data. Found this [How do I move a column (with contents) to another table in a Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135600/how-do-i-move-a-column-with-contents-to-another-table-in-a-rails-migration) which has a migration. And I thought I could mimic that, but this isn't working.

```
class CopyContentToContentPlainText < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    Doc.find_each do |d|
      content_plain_text = action_text_rich_texts.record_id[d].content.body.to_plain_text
      Content.create!(doc_id: d.id, content_plain_text: content_plain_text)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm lost in getting an ActionText field. `record_id` corresponds to the `doc_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already define `before_save`

```rb
before_save { self.content_plain_text = content.body.to_plain_text }
```

then whenever you call `a_doc.save`, the `before_save` will be triggered , hence, it's `content_plain_text` will be assigned to `content.body.to_plain_text`.

so you could update `content_plain_text` for all `Doc` records just simple call `save`

```rb
class CopyContentToContentPlainText < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    Doc.find_each(&:save)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Much closer. Error: `undefined method `to_plain_text' for nil:NilClass`. I removed the `.to_plain_text` and `rails db:migrate DRY_RUN=true` went. I've never done a dry run, but the output makes sense. The method isn't accessible while migrating?

Comment: @Greg that error cause there're some Doc records which have not rich content `content.body`, so you could check nil on `before_save`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that's it. Took me a minute. My migration history got confused. Dry run is going now and output looks right. I've only a few thousand items in the largest model. This might be a problem on a large db, but this is fine for my case. Thanks again. I've backed up my db and will run it for real. The problem hadn't shown up yet because I only had saved on a couple of entries and they all were not nil.